# Storing my API token in local storage is wrapping the token in double quotes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When my API returns a session token, I save it in local storage using this function:

```
export const storeItem = (key: string, item: any) => {
  if (!localStorage) return;

  try {
    return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error storing item ${key} to localStoragee`, err);
  }
};
```

I call in my react redux action:

```
storeItem('authToken', resp.data.token);
```

The wierd thing is that when the token is saved in my local storage and I view it in chrome dev tools, the token is wrapped in double quotes like:

```
"abc123"
```

And then when I pass this token in a querystring to my API, it looks like:

```
token="abc"
```

(but the double quotes are encoded with %22)

Why is this happening and how can I remove this quotes in the first place?

**Update**
I am building the querystring like this:

```
let authToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
let url = API_ROOT + '/sessions/destroy?token=' + authToken;


export const getItemFromStorage = (key: string) => {
  if (!localStorage) return;

  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error getting item ${key} from localStorage`, err);
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you creating your query string? Double quote characters should definitely be escaped

Comment: @DerekNguyen I updated my q with the details on how I am building the URL

Comment: Ah I think the answer below is correct, when you pass a string to JSON.stringify() it adds unnecessary quotation mark (in your localStorage.setItem()). Perhaps you could check if item is a string, then store it without stringifying?

Comment: actually I think what is happening is I am storing it using storeItem function, but when I was retrieving it I was doing it directly using localstorage.getitem.

Comment: FWIW, when I tried to store a string is localStorage and view with dev tool, it doesn't have quotation mark, which is why I thought the problem is at `localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item))`. Curious to see if it's something else

Answer (score 5):

You're stringifying as JSON (which adds the `"`), and not parsing.

You should either parse when reading localStorage (but it looks useless). Or just store the string without encoding it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem('myData', data);
```